# infinite while loop js

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to push characters into an array as long as they are not vowels.

However, the way I have done so seems to cause a console error where I get a warning for a potential infinite loop.

I thought that the problem might be that there could be a chance that the character may never be a vowel, so the loop could be infinite, but it seems that even when making the while condition something that will definitely end, `while(i<str.length)`, I still get the warning.

Am I missing something? Is somehow the structure I have causing this or is it some other error?

Code:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    let  constantants = [];

    if (
        str[0] == 'a' ||
        str[0] == 'a' ||
        str[0] == 'e' ||
        str[0] == 'i' ||
        str[0] == 'o' ||
        str[0] == 'u'
    ) {
        return str + 'way';
    } 
    else {

        while (str[i] != 'a' ||
        str[i] != 'a' ||
        str[i] != 'e' ||
        str[i] != 'i' ||
        str[i] != 'o' ||
        str[i] !='u'){

    constantants.push(str[i]);
     }
        return str.slice(constantants.length) + constantants + 'ay';
    }
  }
}

translatePigLatin('california');
```

Comment: You should increment `i` in `while` loop.

Comment: The console warning hit the nail on the head. Think about when the value `i` will change in your current code.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. added `i++;` at the end of the while loop, but the problem was not fixed until I changed all the `| |` operators to `&&`. I did this because of trial and error and do not understand the logic behind it. Why does this make a difference?